# MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing where a level is not (!=) a value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

How do you slice the following df such that the second level != two.

In my real world case my second level are date ranges and I want to be able to select everything except for one date.

From [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

```
In [1]: arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
                 ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
In [2]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
In [4]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
In [38]: df = df.T

In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
                     A         B         C
first second                              
bar   one     0.895717  0.410835 -1.413681
      two     0.805244  0.813850  1.607920
baz   one    -1.206412  0.132003  1.024180
      two     2.565646 -0.827317  0.569605
foo   one     1.431256 -0.076467  0.875906
      two     1.340309 -1.187678 -2.211372
qux   one    -1.170299  1.130127  0.974466
      two    -0.226169 -1.436737 -2.006747

In [66]: df.xs('one', level='second')
Out[66]: 
              A         B         C
first                              
bar    0.895717  0.410835 -1.413681
baz   -1.206412  0.132003  1.024180
foo    1.431256 -0.076467  0.875906
qux   -1.170299  1.130127  0.974466
```

I am surprised that the documentation @ pandas.pydata.org is so poor. There are NO explanations for any of the examples. Its like the documentation was written by experts for people who are already well experienced with all features of pandas.

Why doesn't the documentation provide the code to re-produce the example?

Comment: If you going to use the advanced features of pandas without being schooled in/ learning the basics, You WILL find the docs hard to read. The docs are progressive. They dont repeat the basics.

Comment: Can you point me to a good resource/tutorial to learn the basics? I've been going through various resources like Youtube workshops by Wes.M and others as well as documentation. However, I have yet to find a really good source to learn a solid foundation.

Comment: https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/UsingPandas.html  I really like the work here, fast paced. hits the key highlights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
                    A         B         C
first second                              
bar   one    -0.350640 -1.761671  0.253923
      two    -0.036557  0.212322  0.537106
baz   one    -1.597584 -0.301356 -0.634428
      two     2.340900 -0.356272 -0.985386
foo   one     0.122753 -0.333827 -0.620175
      two     0.423211 -0.570563 -1.245026
qux   one    -0.972814 -0.878836 -1.030892
      two     0.312855 -0.191677  0.700006


df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('second') != 'one' ]

                    A         B         C
first second                              
bar   two    -0.036557  0.212322  0.537106
baz   two     2.340900 -0.356272 -0.985386
foo   two     0.423211 -0.570563 -1.245026
qux   two     0.312855 -0.191677  0.700006


df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('second') != 'two' ]
                     A         B         C
first second                              
bar   one    -0.350640 -1.761671  0.253923
baz   one    -1.597584 -0.301356 -0.634428
foo   one     0.122753 -0.333827 -0.620175
qux   one    -0.972814 -0.878836 -1.030892
```